# Keep eliminating data points until good correlation coefficient is obtained-using Python

Tags: regression, correlation, python, outliers

I have been trying to find out a way in order to eliminate outliers from a dataset. The outliers are removed the following way: Any value which results into a 10% reduction in R2 value needs to be removed. When 4.2 in A-data set got replaced with 1.3 (in B-dataset), it changed the R2 >10% and thus was eliminated in the C-dataset.

However, when 0.7 in A was replaced with 0.9, it would not change the correlation coefficient by 10% and thus was not removed from C-dataset.

An image is attached herewith.

[image]

In the image, -plot A has R2 of 1.0 -plot B has R2 of 0.8294 (1.3 is the outlier since it causes >10% lowering of R2 values) -plot C has R2 of 1.0 (on removing 1.3 from the dataset)

How do I go about this issue. I need to use python to get to the solution. Out of the 10 data points a maximum of only 3 data points can be removed inorder to improve the correlation.

I apologize if this question was asked before. Thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: Could you clarify what the "issue" is exactly?  When you're inventing a new procedure, as you are here, it's especially important to be explicit about what you're trying to accomplish, how you measure how well you have done, and what you are finding wrong or problematic about the results.

Comment: Sure Whuber, apologies for not being clear. I have say 10 data points which give a straight line plot. For my project, I can get rid of 3/10 data points. The criteria is to have a strong correlation (r2) in case 3/10 data points have heavy noise. I can remove 3 data points! However, for every event, I get 10 data points. For an event to pass, 7/10 points must have a strong correlation. Other three can be weak. I have 10000s of such events and thus doing it manually (which is the easiest) is next to impossible. Where I am failing is say 2/10 points will have heavy noise which lowers R2.

Comment: I'm getting a glimmer of what you're doing, but it doesn't seem to have been expressed in your post itself.  It sounds like you want an algorithm for finding exactly three out of each ten points whose removal maximizes the $R^2$ of the remaining seven--but I'm not sure about that because it's a rather draconian measure and seems likely to bias many results and eliminate useful data.

Comment: Hi Whuber, exactly that's what I mean. We are pretty sure that it won't be biasing the data neither eliminate useful data since we are trying to screen out 10000s of events and then focus on those which have 7/10 data points to understand what happened to those three data points, why did they go off?. My email id: chemgc205 (at) gmail (dot) com If we can please discuss there?

Comment: Why not just use a brute force algorithm?  There are only 120 possible solutions in any case, so even with tens of thousands of cases it's only a few seconds' computation.  I still wouldn't characterize this as "eliminating outliers," though, and despite your explanations it is difficult to see how this approach would not be biased.  But if the bias is acceptable in your application, that's fine.  Just beware.

Comment: Hi Whuber, thanks for the reply. Will be very thankful to you if it is possible for you to email me.

Comment: Please stop asking people to email you offsite. This is not a site for finding free private consulting, it's a question and answer site - answers to good questions here benefit many people rather than one person at a time, and that's a primary motivation for many people to donate time here. If you want consulting, many people point to their contact details for such tasks on their profile. If someone doesn't do so you may assume they're not looking for such work here (though some can also be found in other ways).

Comment: Glen_b, Apologies for that. Did not know about it. Won't repeat the mistake again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be similar to what you are looking for:

```
import numpy, scipy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import scipy.stats
import copy

xyDataPairs = [[1.1, 0.1], [2.2, 2.1],[3.3, 3.4], [4.4, 4.2],[5.0, 5.6],[6.7,6.9]]

minDataPoints = len(xyDataPairs) - 3

# utility function
def UniqueCombinations(items, n):
    if n==0:
        yield []
    else:
        for i in range(len(items)):
            for cc in UniqueCombinations(items[i+1:],n-1):
                yield [items[i]]+cc

bestR2 = 0.0
bestDataPairCombination = []
bestParameters = []

for pairs in UniqueCombinations(xyDataPairs, minDataPoints):
    x = []
    y = []
    for pair in pairs:
        x.append(pair[0])
        y.append(pair[1])
    fittedParameters = numpy.polyfit(x, y, 1) # straight line
    modelPredictions = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, x)
    absError = modelPredictions - y
    Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(y))
    if Rsquared > bestR2:
        bestR2 = Rsquared
        bestDataPairCombination = copy.deepcopy(pairs)
        bestParameters = copy.deepcopy(fittedParameters)


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    x = []
    y = []
    for pair in bestDataPairCombination:
        x.append(pair[0])
        y.append(pair[1])

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(x, y,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(x), max(x))
    yModel = numpy.polyval(bestParameters, xModel)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
print('best parameters"', bestParameters)
print('best R-squared:', bestR2)
```

Comment: Hi James, this works great! My data is in excel. So how do I modify xyDataPairs row inorder to make it a dynamic dataset? I mean I have say 100 sequences which have one to ten data points per sequence. How do we modify the code so that for every sequence (which consists of 10 data points), I get one correlation-coefficient? I am thinking how do we modify the row xyDataPairs in-order to make it dynamic for 10 x and y for every sequence (there are 100 sequences which means in the end there will be 100 plots). Thanks again!

Comment: Just to be specific, the excel file has 10 columns and 100*10 rows (100 being number of events/sequences).

Comment: My purpose in posting the code was to illustrate a principle (in code) that might be useful in solving the immediate problem, and since I do not use Microsoft products I cannot answer this follow-up question regarding excel. My advice is to post the question on stackoverflow.com which is more aligned with this type of programming question.

Comment: One more question: If say I want to keep data point 10 ( as constant (should not be affected by deleting three points), then how do I go about doing it? It is similar to "choose from data points 1 to 9 and keep data point 10 untouched even if it messes up R2 completely"

Comment: I would have a separate list of required data points, and always append it to my "combinations list" before curve fitting. There are good reasons for doing this, such as ensuring that you include maximum and minimum data range values.

Comment: Exactly James! I spoke to my advisor and he told we need to keep the Max and Min data points in the plot for sure. Say Data set 1 and Dataset 10 cannot be deleted. This implies that out of 8 points, I can delete 3 points maximum. Can you please point me out to how to go about this-some example of code? You are great!!!

Comment: This single line of code shows how to add two lists and it will run at a Python command prompt, as Python accepts semicolons. Without the quotes, run: "a = [1,2,3];b = [5,6,7];c=a+b;print(c)"

Comment: Thanks James, here a=required data points, b=three data points can be deleted form 8 data points. Thanks a ton again!!!

Comment: I tried to tweak the code: Requireddatapoints=[[5.0,350], [3.0,330]];

xyDataPairs = [[1.0, 100], [1.0, 110], [1.0, 190],[1.0,115], [1.0, 125], [1.0,117], [2,170], [2,175],[4, 350]];

Appendxy=Requireddatapoints+xyDataPairs;

minDataPoints = len(xyDataPairs) - 0

Comment: Even on adding Required datapoints to the code which you helped out with, I am seeing Dataset 3 disappears even though I have written it to be not affected by deletions.

Comment: I mean, data points x=3,5 are hard coded and not affected by minDataPoints function anymore, still it is seen as disappearing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83348/discussion-between-james-phillips-and-excelislife).

Comment: How to get to chat? I tried to message, but don't have privileges it seems.

Comment: You should be able to click the "continue in chat" link, it is automatically made by the site for long-ish discussions.

Comment: I messaged you on Chat, James :)

Comment: Hi James, the code which you suggested works magically when an entire column is considered. However, if I want to get multiple R2 values for x vs y scatter plot (grouped by four countries: USA, UK, Canada and China). Then how do I modify the main code to get to the final result. If you think the reply can be too long, I am OK to start a new question in this respect. Final result needs to have four R2 for four countries.